# VBA Find cell that matches inputbox and select

Tags: vba, excel

The answers to others questions have been extremely helpful.  The intelligent people that are willing to help others solve their problems has me returning to this site frequently. I am VERY new to VBA and a month ago did not even know of its existence.
The Question: I am trying to use an inputbox answer to find and select a cell in ExcelVBA.
Best way to explain is an example
Say I have a tray its label is 5231-4
It has anywhere from 1-10 items on it they are also labeled 5231-4
I need VBA ask for the tray number I enter 5231-4 
it then finds 5231-4 in column C it then selects Column H of corresponding row 
next I would enter the number of all the items ON the tray If they do not match I need a Messagebox with an ERROR Does not match(ignoring empty cells)!

```
Sub crossingharvestsheet()
Dim ID As String, Item1 As String, Item2 As String, Item3 As String, Item4 As String, 
Item5 As String, Item6 As String, Item7 As String, Item8 As String, Item9 As String, 
Item10 As String
Do
'Asks tray to be entered
    ID = InputBox("Scan tray ID")
'Now I need to find Cell in column C matching ID and Column H of same row

'I will then have it enter each number into the cell of row 
'so at the end it will make sure all the values are the same
    Item1 = InputBox("First item")
    ActiveCell = Item1
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item2 = InputBox("Second item")
    ActiveCell = Item2
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item3 = InputBox("Third item")
    ActiveCell = Item3
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item4 = InputBox("Fourth item")
    ActiveCell = Item4
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item5 = InputBox("Fifth item")
    ActiveCell = Item5
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item6 = InputBox("Sixth item")
    ActiveCell = Item6
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item7 = InputBox("Seventh item")
    ActiveCell = Item7
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item8 = InputBox("Eighth item")
    ActiveCell = Item8
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item9 = InputBox("Ninth item")
    ActiveCell = Item9
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Item10 = InputBox("Tenth item")
    ActiveCell = Item10
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

End sub
```

This is how far I was able to make it biggest issue is finding and selecting the cell that matches the data from input box.

Comment: I guess I am super confused at what youre trying to do. Are you finding a value in column c and making every value in that row the same value? Help me understand what youre after

Comment: You question is not clear. Also your code doesn't help because all it does is gather user input and write ti into cells, we can't see what else you want to do with it. Please try to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find() to locate a value in a range:

```
Dim f As Range

Set f = Activesheet.Range("C:C").Find(what:=ID, lookat:=xlwhole)

If Not f Is Nothing Then

    'work with f

Else

    Msgbox "Couldn't find tray '" & ID & "'   !"

End If
```